# Prove that $H$ is normal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ with the property that no other subgroup of $G$ has order $|H|$. Prove that $H$ is normal.

My attempt:

To show that $H$ is normal, I need to show that for any $g,h \in G$, $ghg^{-1}\in H$.

Let the order of $G=n$ and let the order of $H=k$. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then $k$ divides $n$ and the identity element $e$ is both $G$ and $H$. Also for any $a,b \in H$, $ab^{-1}\in H$.

Since $k$ divides $n$, $n=qk$ for some integer $q$.

$a^{n}=a^{qk}=e$...

(I don't think this proof is getting me anywhere. I think I need a hint about what does "$H$ being a subgroup of $G$ such that no other subgroup of $G$ has order $|H|$" imply...)

Comment: Just show gSg^-1 is a group. If your group is normal, this group is just S.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: for any $\;x\in G\;$ , we have that $\;H^x:=x^{-1}Hx\;$ is a subgroup of $\;G\;$ of order $\;|H|\;$ .

Answer (score 4):

HINT: For $g\in G$ let $H^g=\{ghg^{-1}:h\in H\}$, and show that $H^g$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Just a quibble, but if you're going to write conjugation as a right action, the inverse should be on the left: $x^{-1}Hx$.  Otherwise ``associativity" doesn't hold: $H^{xy} = (xy)^{-1}Hxy = y^{-1} x^{-1}Hxy = (H^x)^y$

Comment: @SpamIAm: In fact I normally do write it $H^g=g^{-1}Hg$, but to avoid confusion I chose to follow the OP’s convention.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $gHg^{-1}$ must be a subgroup of $G$. It also has size $|H|$. But there is only one of these groups, namely $H$ itself. Thus, $gHg^{-1}=H$.

Comment: Could you explain why the order of $gHg^{-1}$ is the same as the order of $H$?

Comment: If you consider it as a mapping from $H$ to $gHg^{-1}$, then $gh_1g^{-1}=gh_2g^{-1}$ implies $h_1=h_2$, so the mapping is one-to-one. Another way of looking at is is that, by the same logic, the kernel is trivial, so by the first isomorphism theorem, they have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

You can say more: $H$ is characteristic. In fact, an automorphism of $G$ has to send $H$ in itself, because it is the only subgroup with order $|H|$; so it is also normal (in particular, it is fixed by an inner automorphism).

Comment: what is an "even characteristic?"

Comment: Sorry, i mean characteristic! It is fixed by every automorphism of $G$.